# How do I style a textarea's currently selected line/row?

Tags: css, textarea

I have a `textarea`. When full of text on many lines, it frequently blurs together to my eyes. In my text editor, I'm used to having the currently selected line/row styled with a different background color from the overall document/window. I want the same thing for my `textarea`.

How do I do this in CSS? I hope it's possible, because it would be *massively* useful.

Searching online finds only irrelevant nonsense, as usual.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: Not doable using css only. You can use javascript to highlight specific row. But if you expect to keep the highlight while writing Iam afraid its not possible. The only way I can think of is to use image as background of the textarea and change its position based on number of rows and current cursor position.